# Filter sublists result in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, filter, sublist

I have a menu system where **MenuTabs** - the top level, they contain **Menu** and Menu contains **MenuItem** s.

Each level item has a list of user **Role** s it should be visible for.

I need to create a database query to select MenuTabs which contains only visible Menus with visible MenuItems for the current User. Is any way to do it with SQL query?

I use JPA and MySql, but any SQL query would be helpful.

As input data, I have a list of roles for the current user and I need to build right menu system for him/her. So user will see only allowed **MenuTabs** / **Menus** / **MenuItems**

Classes:

```
class MenuTab { 
   List<Menu> menu; 
   List<Role> userRoles;
}

class Menu {
   List<MenuItem> menuItems; 
   List<Role> userRoles;
}

class MenuItem {
   List<Role> userRoles;
}

class User {
   List<Role> userRoles;
}
```

Tables:

```
menutab            menutab_menu              menutab_role
  id                  menutabId                 menutabId
                      menuId                    roleId


menu               menu_menuitem             menu_role
  id                  menuId                    menuId
                      menuitemId                roleId


menuitem           menuitem_role
  id                  menuitemId
                      roleId


role
   id

user                user_role
   id                 userId
                      roleId
```

Comment: If you want SQL answers, table structures would be more helpful than class structures (although I assume they will be similar).

Comment: Table structures are the same, we use JPA (Hibernate) and it creates tables from Java code. I can provide structure if they are needed. Thank you for the comment

Comment: I think they are needed.

Comment: Would be great to see what you have tried so far. It might so happen that you only need some pointers in the right direction. (Besides, it is always nicer to think that you are just helping someone rather than doing their job for them.) And there's a question on a different point. Should MenuTabs, Menus and MenuItems match *all* the roles supplied in the input list, or would it be enough to match at least one?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do with a query. I was trying to do something like this:   SELECT tab FROM MenuTab tab WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab.userRoles role WHERE role MEMBER OF :rolesList) It's JPA query, I haven't tried to write SQL query

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Hibernate you dont have to deal with sql
i am not familiar with Hibernate but in NHibernate you could utilize HQL like that :

```
var _query = DetachedCriteria.For<MenuTab>()
                                .Add(Restrictions.In("userRoles", listOfRoles)
                                .Add(Restrictions.In("MenuItem.userRoles", listOfRoles);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL I might perhaps do something like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM menutab_menu tm
  INNER JOIN menu_menuitem mi ON tm.menuId     = mi.menuId
  INNER JOIN menutab t        ON tm.menutabId  = t.Id
  INNER JOIN menu m           ON tm.menuId     = m.Id
  INNER JOIN menuitem i       ON mi.menuitemId = i.Id
WHERE
  t.Id IN (
    SELECT tr.menutabId
    FROM menutab_role tr
      INNER JOIN user_role ur ON tr.roleId = ur.roleId
    WHERE ur.userId = @userId
  )
  AND m.Id IN (
    SELECT mr.menutabId
    FROM menu_role mr
      INNER JOIN user_role ur ON mr.roleId = ur.roleId
    WHERE ur.userId = @userId
  )
  AND i.Id IN (
    SELECT ir.menutabId
    FROM menuitem_role ir
      INNER JOIN user_role ur ON ir.roleId = ur.roleId
    WHERE ur.userId = @userId
  )
```

It is assumed that `@userId` is the current user ID, which is passed to the query as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to translate it into JPA and post the result

Comment: Thanks Andriy, your script works in my DB, but I cannot do it with JPA. I was trying this `SELECT DISTINCT tab FROM MenuTab tab JOIN tab.userRoles tr JOIN tab.menus menu JOIN menu.items item JOIN menu.userRoles mr JOIN item.userRoles ir  WHERE  tr IN (:rolesList) AND mr IN  (:rolesList) AND ir IN  (:rolesList)` but it returns nothing. Also I've tried without items, to get just menuTabs and menus, but it returned visible tabs with all menus inside. I've decided to do filtering with Java. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: @Svetlana: My pleasure! As far as I know, you can't parametrise an `IN()` list like that. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause "Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?"), and also check out its **Linked** section, which contains references to many similar questions. Maybe some of them could be of help to you.

Comment: `IN (:rolesList)` works for us in other places and I use it to get the menu tabs, so I think it's not the reason of fail. Thanks for the links I will look at them